# Chrome Javascript error "WebkitURL is deprecated"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a client for who says their website will not open on "some" of their computers. It opens on others but not on some.

http://www.rwhampton.com

They checked the Chrome Javascript Console and found these errors which they think is causing the problem. It is a WordPress site, so I'm thinking it must have something to do with a WordPress plugin, because I don't have anything in my code that looks like this. Can someone point me in the right direction here? I just don't know what these errors mean. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

You can view the errors here:

http://rwhampton.com/stuff/hamptonerrors.jpg

Comment: This warning is from SoundCloud's JS: https://w.soundcloud.com/player/assets/widget-19642f51.js They are using code like `window.webkitURL || window.URL` and `window.MozBlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.BlobBuilder`, favoring the experimental/deprecated API's for some unknown reason (probably not a good one). Anyhow, I doubt these warnings and errors relate to your problem.

Comment: Thank you, Alexander! That's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

you can use 'URL' instead 'webkitURL', any way this is just warning it would not break your code.

Client machine needs to have [google cast](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-cast/boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd) chrome extension to access this web site.

Comment: Thank you, venkat7668! Just for my own information, do you know why their machine would need that extension? Is it an indication that they are using some particular type of computer? Thanks again.

Comment: Look at the source of www-embed-player.js (loaded from s.ytimg.com, it's YouTube static files CDN). You'll find the following:

function Wj(a){return"chrome-extension://"+a+"/cast_sender.js"}